# Spring -- JPA projections resolved by interface method order rather than name in the presence of an `@Query` annotation?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql, projection

It's been my understanding that when creating a projection in Spring JPA, fields get resolved by name.

That does not seem to be the case when using `@Query` annotations.

Is this expected behaviour or is something wrong with my query?

Let's say I have an entity

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "foo")
public class Foo {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "code")
    private String code;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    ... much more that we are not interested in ...
}
```

We just want to extract the `id`, `name` and `code` properties. So let's write a simple projection interface:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer> {
    FooTestProjection findOneByCode(String code);

    interface FooTestProjection {
        Integer getId();

        String getName();

        String getCode();
    }
}
```

And a test to veriy what we are doing:

```
@Test
void fooTestProjections() {
    Foo targetFoo = repository.saveAndFlush(testData.getFoo());

    getEntityManager().clear();

    FooTestProjection testProjection = repository.findOneByCode(targetFoo.getCode());

    assertThat(testProjection.getId()).isEqualTo(targetFoo.getId());
    assertThat(testProjection.getName()).isEqualTo(targetFoo.getName());
    assertThat(testProjection.getCode()).isEqualTo(targetFoo.getCode());

}
```

**WORKS**

Expectation, here, is that properties are resolved by name. So let's switch the `getCode()` and the `getName()` in our projection interface:

```
interface FooTestProjection {
    Integer getId();

    String getCode();

    String getName();
}
```

Yup, still **WORKS**.

Now, let's say we want projections for all our `Foo`s and we want to do it using an `@Query`.

(Motivation: we eventually want to construct a projection containing properties of unrelated tables, so we use an `@Query` to `LEFT JOIN` them.)

So let's adjust our repository method:

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Integer> {
    @Query("SELECT" +
        " f.id AS fooId," +
        " f.name AS fooName," +
        " f.code AS fooCode" +
        " FROM Foo  f"
    )
    List<FooTestProjection> findProjections();

    interface FooTestProjection {
        Integer getFooId();

        String getFooName();

        String getFooCode();
    }
}
```

and our test:

```
@Test
void fooTestProjections() {
    Foo targetFoo = repository.saveAndFlush(testData.getFoo());

    getEntityManager().clear();

    FooTestProjection testProjection = repository.findProjections().get(0);

    assertThat(testProjection.getFooId()).isEqualTo(targetFoo.getId());
    assertThat(testProjection.getFooName()).isEqualTo(targetFoo.getName());
    assertThat(testProjection.getFooCode()).isEqualTo(targetFoo.getCode());
}
```

**WORKS**

Test green, everything alright, no?

*No.*

Our expectations, here, was that Spring would look at the result set we construct and match them to the projection interface via the column alias we define.

That is not the case.

Let's switch the `getFooCode()` and `getFooName()` in our interface, *but not in our query*:

```
@Query("SELECT" +
    " f.id AS fooId," +
    " f.name AS fooName," +
    " f.code AS fooCode" +
    " FROM Foo  f"
)
List<FooTestProjection> findProjections();

interface FooTestProjection {
    Integer getFooId();

    String getFooCode();

    String getFooName();
}
```

**FAILS**

Why does it fail? Because *now*, the `getFooCode()` returns the `name` of the `targetFoo` and `getfooName()` returns the `code` of the `targetFoo`.

So if we switch the selection arguments to again match the interface order ...

```
@Query("SELECT" +
    " f.id AS fooId," +
    " f.code AS fooCode," +
    " f.name AS fooName" +
    " FROM Foo  f"
)
List<FooTestProjection> findProjections();

interface FooTestProjection {
    Integer getFooId();

    String getFooCode();

    String getFooName();
}
```

This **WORKS** again.

I find this exceedingly counter-intuitive to the point I'm questioning the validity of my query.

Would appreciate it if somebody could shed some light onto this behaviour.

Comment: can you please put only the case which is not working. This is too much info I would say

Comment: @pvpkiran certainly. It's the case marked with `FAILS` above.

Comment: My guess is that when the mapping is between an entity and a projection, Spring can map field by field without problem. But when the mapping is between a manual query and a projection, since alias are optional and you can use joins and functions that add complexity to the result, Spring simply opts for mapping using field ordering instead of field naming.

Comment: if the query returns foo_name and the interfect is getFooName. It will fail

Answer (score 0):

Mentioned ordering issues when using projection has been fixed with latest version of Hibernate (5.2.1 onwards).
With older hibernate version, keep the columns/alias in the native query in the alphabetical order and it shall work fine.

You may like to check/troubleshoot below method for details

```
org.springframework.data.repository.query.ResultProcessor.ProjectingConverter.toMap(Collection<?>, List<String>)
```